# JavaScript addEventListener not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created an variable which is selecting an Id of #bio , i'm then alerting the bio and getting a value of null.

I'm then adding an addEventListener to the bio variable and adding a focus and input to it, which should run a function called updateCounter();, every time the input box is foucessed on

The problem is the updateCounter isnt running. I'm getting no errors in chrome. Could anyone provide a solution and explain where i'm going wrong please ?

```js
var bio = document.getElementById('#bio'); // <textarea> element
alert(bio);

addEventListener(bio, 'focus', updateCounter); // Call updateCounter() on focus
addEventListener(bio, 'input', updateCounter); // Call updateCounter() on input

function updateCounter(e) {
  alert('Update Counter ran');
}
```

```html
<input name="title-input" id="bio" type="text" placeholder="Insert Title" />
```

Comment: Your code represents javascript, not jquery. In jquery addEventListener(bio, 'focus', updateCounter); becomes $("#bio).on("focus",updateCounter(){});

Comment: how is `addEventListener` defined?

Comment: @KevinB It's a standard JS function.

Comment: @Barmar no, document.addEventListener is a standard dom api function. :) or node.addEventListener, etc. though... i guess it would still be there due to it being on window.

Comment: So if you knew that, why did you ask? Just being passive-aggressive instead of just correcting his misunderstanding of how to call it?

Comment: I'm learning and I got confused between javascript and Jquery. I've solved my problem now knowing this. I swear every time I ask a basic question on this site people have a go at me for asking. Isnt that the point in this site?

Answer (score 3):

Aside from some syntax errors, the main reason it's not working is because [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is a method that operates on a DOM element.

Therefore you need to change:

```
addEventListener(bio, 'focus', updateCounter);
addEventListener(bio, 'input', updateCounter);
```

to:

```
bio.addEventListener('focus', updateCounter);
bio.addEventListener('input', updateCounter);
```

In addition, you don't need to include the `#` character in the `.getElementById()` method:

```js
var bio = document.getElementById('bio');

bio.addEventListener('focus', updateCounter);
bio.addEventListener('input', updateCounter);
 
function updateCounter(e) {
  console.log('Logging to the console.');      
}
```

```html
<input name="title-input" id="bio" type="text" placeholder="Insert Title"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've written vanilla JavaScript here, not jQuery.

However, this is a simple fix: you pass the `id` without `#` to `document.getElementById`. You can fix this by adjusting your selection to be: `document.getElementById('bio')`. You'll also want to be more explicit: make it `bio.addEventListener('focus', updateCounter);`.